# Default value for static boolean variable

Tags: programming-languages

I'm trying to debug the v8 javascript engine.while debugging i found a instruction "static bool has_terminated".Can anyone tell me what is the default value for a "static boolean variable" ?

Answer (score 0):

For a boolean in most languages that allow uninitialized use it's false (unless it's on the stack or heap in which sometimes there's no guarantee).

Comment: @Ramos: I want the default value of it in heap. why there's no guarantee for the default value of bool variable when it is on stack or heap?

Comment: @DSC, when it's on the heap (unless allocated using calloc or malloc and then memset or something like that) the memory is not guaranteed to be clear and may contain junk. On the stack likewise because that stack frame may have been previously used and still contain junk (which is why unintialized use is usually a warning).